# How to convert exponent and coefficient to an integer value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, scientific-notation

****UPDATED****

How to convert an exponent and coefficient to an integer? Is there a built-in method in SQL?

This is the value in scientific notation `6,1057747657e+011`

Comment: Do you have two integers? An exponent and a coefficient?

Comment: What do you mean by that? An integer has no notation. You format it using a specific notation when you convert it to string, or you use a specific notation when writing an integer literal or parsing a string to an integer. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @i BIGINT;

SET @s = '6.1057747657e+011';
SET @i = CAST(@s as FLOAT(53));

SELECT @i;
```

Results 610577476570

You need to store the result as a BIGINT because the number is too large for a 32-bit INT. Note that an implicit conversion is being done from FLOAT(53) to BIGINT.

If you want to control the rounding, you can use the ROUND(), FLOOR() or CEILING() functions. For example:

```
SET @i = ROUND(CAST(@s as FLOAT(53)), -2);
```

If it is possible that the input string might contain an invalid number, you would need to add error handling.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @i BIGINT;

SET @s = 'rubbish';

BEGIN TRY
    SET @i = CAST(@s as FLOAT(53));
    SELECT @i;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- error handling goes here
END CATCH
```

(Tested using T-SQL on SQL Server 2012.)

Answer (score 0):

I think like this but to make into a integer I guess use BigInteger? let me research more

```
   try {
      Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("6.1057747657e+011"));
   }   
   catch (OverflowException) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of the Double type.",
                        value);
   }
```

Different answer below.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The "e" or "E" character, which indicates that the value is
>   represented in exponential (scientific) notation. The value parameter
>   can represent a number in exponential notation if style includes the
>   NumberStyles.AllowExponent flag.

```
BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse("-903145792771643190182");
string[] specifiers = { "C", "D", "D25", "E", "E4", "e8", "F0", 
                        "G", "N0", "P", "R", "X", "0,0.000", 
                        "#,#.00#;(#,#.00#)" };

foreach (string specifier in specifiers)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));

// The example displays the following output: 
//       C: ($903,145,792,771,643,190,182.00) 
//       D: -903145792771643190182 
//       D25: -0000903145792771643190182 
//       E: -9.031458E+020 
//       E4: -9.0315E+020 
//       e8: -9.03145793e+020 
//       F0: -903145792771643190182 
//       G: -903145792771643190182 
//       N0: -903,145,792,771,643,190,182 
//       P: -90,314,579,277,164,319,018,200.00 % 
//       R: -903145792771643190182 
//       X: CF0A55968BB1A7545A 
//       0,0.000: -903,145,792,771,643,190,182.000 
//       #,#.00#;(#,#.00#): (903,145,792,771,643,190,182.00)
```

In your case you might do

```
BigInteger value = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("6.1057747657e+011", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You must have `.NET Framework 4.5` or higher for this to work.

Comment: This is not a solution.